# WKWebView crash with a KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS error

Tags: javascript, swift, cocoa, wkwebview

I'm building a Mac app using a WKWebView. There is a lot of biding between JavaScript and the Swift code with the `webview.evaluateJavaScript` Swift side function and the `webkit.messageHandlers[funName].postMessage` JavaScript side function.

At some point and after several hours of utilisation, the app crash with this following stack trace:

```
    Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
    0   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff926d95fe WTFCrash + 62
    1   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff9250dff6 JSC::MachineThreads::makeUsableFromMultipleThreads() + 38
    2   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff9250e079 JSGlobalContextCreateInGroup + 89
    3   com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff928906ba -[JSContext initWithVirtualMachine:] + 122
    4   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d62699f ScriptMessageHandlerDelegate::didPostMessage(WebKit::WebPageProxy&, WebKit::WebFrameProxy&, WebCore::SerializedScriptValue&) + 135
    5   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d6838d3 WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::didPostMessage(IPC::Connection*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long,         IPC::DataReference const&) + 217
    6   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d60e514 void IPC::handleMessage<Messages::WebUserContentControllerProxy::DidPostMessage, WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy, void (        WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)>(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&,         WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy*, void (WebKit::WebUserContentControllerProxy::*)(IPC::Connection*, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, IPC::DataReference const&)) + 134
    7   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d58f2d2 IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&) + 120
    8   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d6995d8 WebKit::WebProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection*, IPC::MessageDecoder&) + 24
    9   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff8d542ee0 IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::MessageDecoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::MessageDecoder> >) + 94
```

I cannot find anything on Internet regarding the WTFCrash error. Does anybody have already encountered the same problem?

All callbacks are executed in the main thread with the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...})` block.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you ever figure this out?